# How can i filter firestore data by a field in another collection in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdzrN.png)I have tried to assign the field value to a local variable but its not working

```
getData() async {
        String userId = 'userId';
        Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).snapshots();
        var snapshot;
        var userDocument = snapshot.data;
        String _myAddress = userDocument["address"];
        return Firestore.instance
            .collection('letters')
            .where("source Box", isEqualTo: _myAddress)
            .snapshots();
      }
```

Comment: Can you add an image of your database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your question more clear but I have tried fixing some obvious problems with your code.

```
getData() async {
        String userId = 'userId';
        var userDocument = await Firestore.instance.collection('user').document(userId).get();


        String _myAddress = userDocument["address"];
        return Firestore.instance
            .collection('letters')
            .where("source Box", isEqualTo: _myAddress)
            .snapshots();
      }
```

- You can get a single document if you know the document Id by calling **get()** directly
- You weren't calling await for asynchronous requests for next time you must wait for such Futures in order to get the result. To understand more about async/await I recommend reading [this](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and more on the topic.

Comment: @JustinWaweru glad I'm helpful if any questions you can comment below.

Comment: Is there a way to match _myAddress to two fields in the database with an or

Comment: I'm trying to match my address to two fields 1.source address and 2.destination address

Comment: you can call multiple where statements when querying